# Создание формы на языке Java

Tags: java, классы, swing

Добрый день. Я новичок, только вот начал учить Java. Недавно я нашёл пример инициализации GUI-формы с помощью Java-кода. Вот как он приведён:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class AbsoluteBoundsTest extends JFrame {

    public AbsoluteBoundsTest(){
        super("Absolute bounds test");
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(null);
        JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First name");
        lblFirstName.setBounds(5,5,95,21);
        JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last name");
        lblLastName.setBounds(5,30,95,21);
        JTextField tfFirstName = new JTextField(20);
        tfFirstName.setBounds(100,5,120,21);
        JTextField tfLastName = new JTextField(20);
        tfLastName.setBounds(100,30,120,21);
        JButton btnOk = new JButton("Ok");
        btnOk.setBounds(65,60,75,21);
        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setBounds(145,60,75,21);
        content.add(lblFirstName);
        content.add(lblLastName);
        content.add(tfFirstName);
        content.add(tfLastName);
        content.add(btnOk);
        content.add(btnCancel);
        setSize(230,130);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(content);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {     
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable thrown) {
            thrown.printStackTrace();
        }
        AbsoluteBoundsTest abt = new AbsoluteBoundsTest();
        abt.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Если я по этому принципу хочу создавать ещё одну форму, то мне её другим классом создавать? Или можно сделать в одном классе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, если экземпляры класса не имеют ссылок на какие-то внешние ресурсы (а в вашем примере они не используют никаких глобальных или ограниченных ресурсов, кроме самого ОЗУ), то все экземпляры этого класса будут независимыми копиями.

*P.S.* Вам следовало бы глубже ознакомиться с самом понятием "класса" в программировании.

- [Java для начинающих. Урок: Классы и объекты.](https://youtu.be/uPK2FVz6qUs)

Comment: Ну хорошо, а если я в Intellij Idea создам два отдельных java класса с этим же кодом, то их можно будет как - то объединить? чтобы из первого класса по нажатию кнопки вызывался второй класс?

Comment: Тогда у вас будет очень сильное дублирование кода, там ведь очень многое будет совпадать. Попробуйте использовать наследование, а общую функциональность вынести в один метод.

Comment: @Slava: Да; вам следует посмотреть/почитать несколько видео-уроков в роде "java классы", "java для начинающих", "java для чайников". Более того, может быть вам даже начать своё обучение с Си, потому, что сама постановка ваши вопросов вопиет о том, что вы очень сильно запутались в самых базовых вещах.

Answer (score 1):

Данный класс запускает программу во фрейме (то есть в окне) и на нем уже строиться то, что написано в конструкторе.
Чтобы вам решить данную задачу, вам нужно написать класс (структуру) и когда нужно создавать объект.
Этим вы сделаете уникальность и можно будет создавать разные формы, на этапе программы, к примеру: через события или после выполнения чего-то другого.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше создать некий абстрактный/обычный класс, и от него сделать двух наследников, имхо.